# Method to retrieve vowels from the string

Tags: c#

I need to create a method by the name "SelectOnlyVowels" and get the vowels out of the string "abc" without altering the code below.

```
const string abc = "asduqwezxc";  //this is the string
                foreach (var vowel in abc.SelectOnlyVowels())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", vowel);
                }
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I think you mean your teacher wants you to create this

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not here to write code for you. If you can give some example of what you have tried we can advise you where you might have gone wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: `var matching = "asduqwezxc".ToLowerInvariant().Intersect(new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' });`

Comment: `str.GroupBy(c => "aeiou".Contains(c)).FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key) ?? Enumerable.Empty<char>();`

Comment: thank you @itsme86

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're looking for is a string extension method

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Here's a working example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string abc = "asduqwezxc";
        foreach (var vowel in abc.SelectOnlyVowels())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", vowel);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class StringManipulation
{
    public static string SelectOnlyVowels(this string text)
    {
        var vowels = "aeiou";
        var result = "";
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            if (vowels.Contains(c))
            {
                result += c;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,would you be so kind to drop me some links for more information on string extension methods if you know of any.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create extension method like this :

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SelectOnlyVowels(this string text)
    {
        var vowels = "aeiou";
        return new String(text.Where(p => vowels.IndexOf(p.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToArray());
    }
}
```